# I want to stack up the list items using the display as block but rather it would hide behind one another

Tags: css

I am trying to make a mega drop down menu. I just want to second list items to stack up like a simple list but they hide behind one another. I don't know where I am make the mistake.

```
nav div .main-ul li{
    display: inline-block;
}

.sub-ul li{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```
<div>

    <ul class="main-ul">

        <li>Item 1

            <ul class="sub-ul">

                <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
                <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
                <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
                <li>Sub Menu Item</li>

            </ul>

        </li>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 1</li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

Just stack up the sub menu item with css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

```
<div>
    <ul class="main-ul">
        <li>Item 1
            <ul class="sub-ul">
                <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
                <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
                <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
                <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div .main-ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
div .main-ul li > .sub-ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: -1px;
    padding: 0;
}
div .main-ul li:hover > .sub-ul {
    display: block;
}
div .main-ul li > .sub-ul > li {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2cz6x0tj/)

Comment: Thank you so much, I finally understood the concept behind it.